# Org-crypt not working

Tags: encryption

Having trouble here, not sure why.

Emacs v25.3.2
Org v9.1.1

In my emacs init file:

```
(setq org-tag-alist '(("@crypt" . ?c) ("@init" . ?i)))

(require 'org-crypt)
(org-crypt-use-before-save-magic)
(setq org-tags-exclude-from-inheritance (quote ("crypt")))
(setq org-crypt-key nil)
```

A heading in `xyz.org` file:

```
* Test :crypt:
This is not encrypted, even after I save and reopen the file.
```

I can't get things at the heading level to encrypt. I even generated gpg keys and substituted public key in `(setq org-crypt-key xxxxxxx)`. What am I missing?

Comment: This all looks good to me. Can't reproduce the failure. What is the effect of `M-x org-encrypt-entry`?

Comment: @MarcoWahl, I get an "enter passphrase" popup (non-emacs, looks like Seahorse). Enter my pgp key passphrase 2x then the heading is encrypted.

Comment: After that, i'm able to `M-x org-encrypt-entry` and `M-x org-decrypt-entry` just fine. Any ideas why this new popup appears? 
Is this an Ubuntu 16.04.3 thing, or related to the version of Emacs/Org-mode i'm using? 
Haven't found this in any other org-crypt tutorials out there.

Comment: This sounds familiar. Are you running on Mac?

Comment: Nope. Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Isn't `org-crypt` supposed to encrypt headings tagged as `* Heading :crypt:` on save? This is most definitely not working in this case.